# SQLite query in Objective C iPhone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, uisearchbar

I am building this application which fetches data from SQLite database tables, when a string is being entered in to UISearchBar, all possible entries should be printed. Right now i am able to fetch all the entries from the table but i am not able to perform the specific search, can anyone help me with the query or give some example to refer?

Comment: In this app, I want to query data from sqlite file, there is a file consisting a table named as "Names", i want to implement a UITextField or SearchBar which will show a list of names similar to the one i entered. Eg: If i enter London than all the names resembling the keyword should be displayed in a list. For this purpose i want to query the table but i do not know how to.

Comment: You need to slow down, get yourself a SQL book and do some reading.  Trying to write SQL when you don't know SQL is an exercise in frustration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE myfield like '%your searchwordhere%'`  by executing this query you can get the words which are having the word of your search keyword.

Comment: thanks but that is only for a single keyword, i have got like thousands of entries in the Sqlite table which i want to search through sqlite table itself. Do you know how to instantiate a string or a object to pass the entered keyword to the sql query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT fieldone, fieldtwo FROM mytable WHERE myfield like '%%SEARCH_TERM_GOES_HERE%%'
```

Comment: thanks but that is only for a single keyword, i have got like thousands of entries in the Sqlite table which i want to search through sqlite table itself. Do you know how to instantiate a string or a object to pass the entered keyword to the sql query.

Comment: Do you want to search for more than one keyword? If yes, try this:       SELECT fieldone, fieldtwo FROM mytable WHERE (myfield like '%%SEARCH_TERM_GOES_HERE%%') OR (myfield like '%%ANOTHER_SEARCH_TERM%%')